# A combinatorial inequality involving a binomial coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to decide which one is greater between $2^{n-1}$ and $0.99~ {n \choose k}$, for $k = n/2$ and $k= n/4$. Is there any value of $k$ for which $2^{n-1}$ is less than $0.99 {n \choose k}$?

In a similar vein, is it true that \begin{equation}
\left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)\sum_{k = n/4}^{n}{n \choose k} \geq 2^{n-1}
\end{equation}

for some polynomially bounded (polynomial over $n$) function $m$?

---

Here is my attempt. The probability of seeing exactly $k$ heads, out of $n$ tries, when tossing a fair coin is

\begin{equation}
{n \choose k} \frac{1}{2^{n}} \leq 1.
\end{equation}

Hence,
\begin{equation}
{n \choose k} \leq 2^{n}.
\end{equation}

This makes me conjecture $2^{n-1}$ is always greater than $0.99~ {n \choose k}$ but I could not prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some hints. The binomial coefficients are unimodal and symmetric, so the middle is the biggest. Their sum is $2^n$. Any individual one will be well under half the total sum except possibly for very small values of $n$ where things are degenerate. There are any number of ways to see this, e.g. using symmetry except perhaps at the middle, using the normal approximation to the binomial, etc.

Comment: Do you have any hints for trying to prove $\left(1 - \frac{1}{m}\right)\sum_{k = n/4}^{n}{n \choose k} \geq 2^{n-1}$ or whether it is even true? I can see how $\sum_{k = n/4}^{n}{n \choose k} \geq 2^{n-1}$, as $\sum_{k = n/2}^{n}{n \choose k} = 2^{n-1}$, but the prefactor of $(1-1/m)$ complicates things.

Comment: @RandomMatrices Use the normal approximation to the binomial. Estimate your sum as an integral of a Gaussian.